# NSScrollView not scroll and size contentView not correct in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nsscrollview

I have a problem: I create 1 NSScollView in XIB. Then i create 20 NSTextFile programmically and add them to ContentView of ScrollView. But when add mutiple NStextfield, scrollview not scroll and many NStextfield has been removed, not show all NSTextField.
This is my code:

```
IBOutlet NSView *contentView;
IBOutlet NSScrollView *ScrollView;
```

Function createDynamictextField:

```
-(void) createLabelDynamic : (int) number andX: (int) x andY : (int) y
{
 for(int i=1; i<=number;i++)
     {
         NSTextField *ssid = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect (x,y,150,100)];
         [ssid setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SSID %d :",i]];
         [ssid setSelectable:NO];
         [ssid setEditable:NO];
         [ssid setBordered:NO];
         [ssid setDrawsBackground:NO];
         [ssid setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];
         [contentView addSubview:ssid];
         y -=30;
         [ssid release];
     }
    [ScrollView  setDocumentView :contentView];
}
```

And if less NStextField, example is 2 NSTextFiels, position of NSTextField is not correct. It seem not autoresize contentView fit ScrollView. Can you help me?

Comment: did you try to set frame to the contentView? try like this: contentView.frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1.0e7, 1.0e7);

Comment: I try add your code, it has space in above, NSTextFiels is at bottom. How i can do put NSTextField programmicall position correctly @stosha

Comment: try insert contentView.frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1.0e7, number * 30); before [ScrollView  setDocumentView :contentView];

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
-(void) createLabelDynamic : (int) number andX: (int) x andY : (int) y
{
     for(int i=1; i<=number;i++)
     {
         NSTextField *ssid = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect (x,y,150,30)];
         [ssid setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SSID %d :",i]];
         [ssid setSelectable:NO];
         [ssid setEditable:NO];
         [ssid setBordered:NO];
         [ssid setDrawsBackground:NO];
         [ssid setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];
         [contentView addSubview:ssid];
         y -=30;
         [ssid release];
     }
    contentView.frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 150, y + number * 30);
    [ScrollView  setDocumentView :contentView];
}
```